# Two part model - conditional expectation

Tags: regression, machine-learning, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, two-step-estimation

I am working on a model to predict a continuous target variable $Y$, given a feature set $F$. $Y$ is product of two continuous variables - $A$ and $B$, where $A \epsilon [0, 1]$ and $B \epsilon (0, \infty)$. $A$ and $B$ are not independent variables, a quick correlation check between $A$ and $B$ gives a PCC of -0.2. Also, I am not clear on how conditional expectations play out here, that is, I understand the following is not accurate:

$E[Y|F] = E[A|F] * E[B|F]$

Is there a way to check if $A$ and $B$ are independent when conditioned on a set of features and hence justify the above formulation? Also, to the original problem of predicting $Y$ given a feature set, are there particular formulations/modeling techniques where I can inject this additional knowledge (of components of $Y$) to make the predictions more accurate?

One of my primary motivations to try to break the prediction problem into two-step is the fact my predictors ($F$) have “dissonant effects” ie. they work in an opposite direction on the two parts on the target variable's component i.e. $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Search for the phrase Loch Ness here, and it will turn up a good thread on this.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to extend the example in the Loch Ness thread to what I am trying to ask here. Let's say instead of the actual revenue B, we are trying to predict the attributed revenue (ie. Y). So Y here is some fraction (A, btw 0 & 1) of the actual revenue (B), that is attributed say to a particular marketing ad. So the problem becomes - "given its a buy how much is the 'attributed' revenue". What I am asking is there a way to say maybe further breakdown the second part in the two-part model suggested in Loch Ness into separately predicting attribution & actual revenue & combining them?

Comment: I think there are several possible ways to set this up. The method I suggested will would work for this, allowing the same variables to have different effects. For example, suppose you modeling expenditure on vacation and the covariate of interest is the number of kids. Having more children typically makes people less likely to go on vacation (negative effect), but conditional on going, the expenditure would be larger (positive effect). Two-part model can handle this, which is similar to the types of problem you would run into with attribution.